# DB app design. enable easy expansion

Tags: database, ms-access, join

I feel that this is a bit of a 'silly' question, but here goes anyway, as it may be useful to someone else.
Also it is a bit long, as I want to give the background to my situation.

Background:
I'm developing a db app to enable us to 'follow' expenses for our various projects. I'm sure that there is already an app out there that could do this, but I'm restricted to using VBA, so MS Access.
I've been told that they don't want to have to learn something 'new', and I'm sure any other 'new' product would require an amount of 'tweaking' to give all 'supplementary' functionality and details we need.

Problem (S):
these may be knock on problems surround my prinicple question, your thoughts are welcome, if it may result in an interesting discussion I am happy to break out each little bit into a new question, but I'm including these things here for completion.

I have mutliple tables that are linked to one another in a 'pathway'
so tables each store information. for simplicity lets think of this as 
Project : Location (geographic) : Person to Visit
(in truth this pathway has another 4 tables in it but...)
As each location can exist in each project I have a 'project_2_location' table that links the tables together
and another 'link' table between each of the intermediate tables others.
so if the tables are A B C and D the link tables are
A_2_B : B_2_C : C_2_D : etc... (I don't do A_2_C and A_2_D).

I also have a 'huge' number of 2 column 'lookup' tables (in fact I have more 'lookup' type tables than I do 'true' tables, whick agravates me in the 'design view').

My main problem / question.
I have another 'set' of tables that are causing me some 'grief' as how best to continue. It is these that are the root of my 'problems'.

I have the 2 tables that link in a one_to_many relationsip, and I use a 'single' value in the parent table to link to the child (the child has its own surrogate key)

Apparently they are not particularly interested in the details in the 'child' table, but I created it as it was the most expedient way in which to make the interface work, and maintain some sort of 'first normal form'.

Now that I have created this child table, I know that they will want to run queries against it in the future (even though at the moment they say that they don't!). To do this they will 'have' to create a join between it, the parent and they granparent table  to extract all the inormation they desire.

so in brief I have

Granparent (which acts as a lookup table of project names).

Parent (which has a foreign key to the PK of the Grandparent, and is a 'oneGranparent_to_ManyParent type relationship).

Child (which has a foreign key to the PK of the Parent, and is a 'oneParent_to_ManyChild type relationship).

So I have the following solutions in my mind.

1) Add in a field in the child that points to the grandparent's PK field (quick easy but redundant, appart from adding the ease for in the future when people want to search this child table).

2) add a link table that links the PK in the Grandparent to the PK in the Child (this seems reaonable enough, and will result in a search that joins only 2 table)

3) leave well alone, (any future search will need to joing the Child to the Parent and Grandparent - which may be too much for the 'non' programmers here!). Also currently I have not been asked to provide this search so 'sorry for them', I did offer it, but the response was 'no, we won't need that'

4) some other solution I am missing.

Personally I'm inclined to go with solution #1, but fancy to run with #3 (out of bloody mindedness), I will likely document the required SQL in the dev notes for creating the search.

Your thoughts and other solutions are very welcome (eg shadow tables and pre-creation of the join table (in #3 via a stored procedure to run whenever someone opens the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to read this with all, the 'quotes' - but a few thoughts from having done similar work:

I don't like to create unnecessary tables, for a few reasons.  First, it's easy to forget to update the extra tables when the source data changes, so things can get out of date.  If you do create these tables, and if there are more than one or two steps to update them, consider a macro to consolidate all the update steps.  Second, it's generally unnecessary.  So I don't like your option 2.

I have the same feeling about option 1, for the same reasons - I don't like to create extra, unnecessary fields, or have to worry about keeping them current.

So that leaves option 3 - which doesn't sound like a bad option to me.  I don't see any basic problem with queries that join multiple tables.  In your case, the Grandparent - Parent - Child link seems pretty easy to use and understand.  You can set this up as a standard query (not a new table) that can be used as necessary to look up the Parent or Grandparent of any Child, and to use in any additional queries you need to develop in the future.

As for the "so sorry for them" - I've always considered projects to be iterative.  It's great to look ahead and anticipate future requirements, but I never expect to have all the requirements fully defined up front.  Every answer and every new capability always seem to create new questions.  Be flexible.

Comment: On reflection I've been coming down more on the side of option 3, and creating a standard query that they can use if they want. Chances are I'll put it there and they'll not realise what this stored query does (I'll obviously document it, but will they ever reads the docs?).